# Incrementing values in a sparse matrix takes very long

Tags: matlab

i'm running the following code, where `M` is a ~200,000 by ~200,000 sparse matrix and `points` is ~200,000 by 2 matrix

```
inds=sub2ind(size(M),points(:,1),points(:,2));
M(inds)=M(inds)+1;
```

the problem is that the second line takes very long to run (15-90 seconds).
the operation takes longer depending on how many of the indices in `inds` are 'new' (i.e. that don't already have a value in the sparse matrix)

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
M = M + sparse(points(:,1),points(:,2),1,size(M,1),size(M,2),size(points,1));
```

[Just so you know,](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

> `S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax)` uses vectors `i`, `j`, and `s` to generate an
>   `m`-by-`n` sparse matrix such that `S(i(k),j(k)) = s(k)`, with space
>   allocated for `nzmax` nonzeros. Vectors `i`, `j`, and `s` are all the same
>   length. Any elements of `s` that are zero are ignored, along with the
>   corresponding values of `i` and `j`. Any elements of `s` that have duplicate
>   values of `i` and `j` are added together.

#### For the curious:

```
M = sprand(200000,200000,1e-6);
points = [randperm(200000) ; randperm(200000)]'; %'//Initialization over
Mo = M;
tic; 
inds=sub2ind(size(Mo),points(:,1),points(:,2));
Mo(inds) = Mo(inds)+1;
toc
tic; 
M = M + sparse(points(:,1),points(:,2),1,size(M,1),size(M,2),size(points,1));
toc
```

Comment: @pseudoDust, how faster did it become?

Comment: @Andrey: You can test it for yourself with the demo code I added